# Extjs: table layout and all items in single row

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I have a simple panel with table:

```
Ext.define('ETaxi.settings.view.mypanel', {
extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
alias: 'widget.mypanel',
record: null,

layout: 'table',
layoutConfig: {
    columns: 2
},
defaults: { padding: 5, margin: 5, border: true },

defaultType: 'label',

items: [{
    text: 'left'
},{
    text: 'right'
},{
    text: 'left'
},{
    text: 'right'
},{
    text: 'left'
},{
    text: 'right'
},{
    text: 'left'
},{
    text: 'right'
}]
});
```

and idea is to get something like that:

```
| left | right |
| left | right |
| left | right |
| left | right |
```

but I see all elements in single row:

```
| left | right | right | left | right | left | right |
```

What I missed? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have tried your code in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rowena19july/4KeHR/). It's working when I change this:

```
layout: 'table',
layoutConfig: {
    columns: 2
},
```

to this:

```
layout: {
    type : 'table',
    columns: 2
},
```